# SQL selecting specific field with defined values

Tags: sql, syntax

I have some look up tables that I don't want to do a join for, but I still want the fields value.

TABLES

Table1

```
ID       Value     LookupID
1         1         1
2         2         2
```

Table2

```
LookupID      Result
 1             Yes
 2              No
```

I'd like to do something like

```
SELECT ID, Value, (if LoopupID =1, yes if =2 no)
FROM Table1
```

Rather than doing a join. I've done this before, but I cannot remember what command/syntax I used to achieve this. I'm trying to avoid using a join as it makes the query take significantly longer to run. There are only 3-4 values that need to be put in the string so it would not be difficult to hard code into the query.

Comment: Why don't you want a join?  The whole point of the table is so that you **don't** hardcode these values.  Small tables like this will usually be kept entirely in memory, so there's essentially no penalty (may be optimized the same as a `CASE` statement, depending on the optimizer).  Note that in the case of internationalization, you use a similar structure for dealing with multiple languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT ID, Value, case when LoopupID =1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as result
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a little more information here...
The case syntax will work for three or more values, as well.
Also, you can name the resultant column with an "as"
and that name will go after the "end" in the case clause.

Like this:

```
case 
when LookupID = 1 then 'Yes' 
when LookupID = 2 then 'Maybe'
else 'No'
end as YesNoMaybeColumn1
```

Note that you probably don't want to do any subqueries inside the values for the "then"s because that likely wouldn't perform well.  It might get optimized though - you could try it out and see what you get as a result.

The reason your Joins aren't fast to begin with though is probably due to the tables not having convenient indices setup correctly.  Lookup table joins like this should normally be blazingly fast if the indices are right.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Value, t2.Result FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.LookupID = t2.LookupID 
ORDER BY t1.ID
```